# How to create a dynamic number of threads?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Currently I create a thread the following way (the normal way)

```
Public loginThread As Thread
Public loginThreadStart As New ThreadStart(AddressOf LogIntoWhatever)
Public callLoggedIn As New MethodInvoker(AddressOf loggedIn)
```

However, what I want to be able to do is something along the lines of (this obviously does not work, and is entirely pseudocode)

```
dim i as integer = 0
for i = 0 to i = 25
Public loginThread(i) as Thread
Public loginThreadStart(i) as New ThreadStart(AddressOf LogIntoWhatever)
next i
Public callLoggedIn as new MethodInvoker(AddressOf loggedIn)
```

Where I could change 25 to whatever I wanted and have that number of threads created. They would all be running an identical sub which does do not make calls of any kind to each other, they don't need knowledge of each other. Is anything like this possible? If so, direction towards a solution would help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
Public Function RunThreads(count as Integer, start As ThreadStart) As List(Of Thread)
  Dim list as New List(Of Thread)
  For i = 0 to count -1 
    Dim thread = new Thread(start)
    thread.Start()
    list.Add(thread)
  Next
  Return list
End Function
```

Or using the thread pool

```
Public Sub RunThreads(count as Integer, callBack as WaitCallBack) 
  For i = 0 To count-1
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callBack)
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This unfortunately has an error on the "Return thread". 'Thread' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: changed the return to list and this works as expected now. Thanks!